# mask a field with no fixed length in crystal reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008

I have a field in crystal reports that displays customer's names. the requirement however is to just display the first 5 characters, which includes spacing as well. whatever comes after the 5th character will be converted into `*` and the spacing shall be displayed as a space still. as the name field varies, how do i accomplish this?

currently i only have this, which displays the first 5 characters and replaces only the 6th character with an `*`

```
Replace({Command.CUST_NAME},MID({Command.CUST_NAME},6),"*")
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems Crystal does not suport regex.

So, i would do a function. Try this:

```
stringvar input := {Command.CUST_NAME};
stringvar output := MID(input, 1, 5);
numbervar i;
for i:=5 to Length (input) step 1 do (
    stringvar aChar := MID(input, i, 1);
    if aChar <> " " then aChar := "*";
    output := output + aChar;
);
output
```

Maybe you will have to handle if {Command.CUST_NAME} is smaller than 5 chars.